# Storing a docker image on dropbox

Tags: docker

I know dockerhub is the best place to store docker images. But is it possible to also store the docker images on disk to a specific folder in particular Dropbox.

When I do `docker images` for instance, I see the list of images but not "where" they are stored on my hard-drive.

```
blahblah@multivac:~] 16s % docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
blahblah/ubuntu      customized          08081314feb5        49 minutes ago      4.87 GB
ubuntu              latest              08081314feb5        49 minutes ago      4.87 GB
ubuntu              <none>              93fd78260bd1        12 days ago         86.2 MB
```

This can be helpful, in the event of loss of the laptop or sudden damage.

Answer (score 0):

Docker images are saved under `/var/lib/docker`. To be more specific, an image comprises of multiple layers and each layer is saved under `/var/lib/docker/<storage-driver>/layers/`.

In case of Mac, things get a bit more complicated because in Docker for Mac actually runs a thin VM and the contents of the VM are stored in `$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`.

You can connect to the Linux VM tty by typing `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty` and from there navigating to the above directories, you will see the result.

Image size can add up quite quickly, I'd recommend not storing on Dropbox - instead use a managed Docker repository such as aforementioned Docker Hub or [Quay](https://quay.io/) or even [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/).